# r create new data frame that matches in rows elements grouped by another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a new data frame from the `df` one below. In the new data frame (`df2`), each element in `df$name` is placed in the first column and matched in its row with other element of `df$name` grouped by `df$group`.

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:2], each=3),
                 name = LETTERS[1:6])

> df
  group name
1     a    A
2     a    B
3     a    C
4     b    D
5     b    E
6     b    F
```

In this example, "A", "B", and "C" in `df$name` belong to "a" in `df$group`, and I want to put them in the same row in a new data frame. The desired output looks like this:

```
  > df2
          V1   V2
    1     A    B
    2     A    C
    3     B    A
    4     B    C
    5     C    A
    6     C    B
    7     D    E
    8     D    F
    9     E    D
    10    E    F
    11    F    D
    12    F    E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:2], each=3),
                 name = LETTERS[1:6])

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%                                      # for every group
  summarise(v = list(expand.grid(V1=name, V2=name))) %>%   # create all combinations of names
  select(v) %>%                                            # keep only the combinations
  unnest(v) %>%                                            # unnest combinations
  filter(V1 != V2)                                         # exclude rows with same names

# # A tibble: 12 x 2
#   V1    V2   
#   <fct> <fct>
# 1 B     A    
# 2 C     A    
# 3 A     B    
# 4 C     B    
# 5 A     C    
# 6 B     C    
# 7 E     D    
# 8 F     D    
# 9 D     E    
# 10 F     E    
# 11 D     F    
# 12 E     F
```

Answer (score 2):

We could do this in `base R` with `merge`

```
out <- setNames(subset(merge(df, df, by.x = 'group', by.y = 'group'),
         name.x != name.y, select = -group), c("V1", "V2"))
row.names(out) <- NULL

out
#   V1 V2
#1   A  B
#2   A  C
#3   B  A
#4   B  C
#5   C  A
#6   C  B
#7   D  E
#8   D  F
#9   E  D
#10  E  F
#11  F  D
#12  F  E
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion its case of self-join. Using `dplyr` a solution can be as:

```
library(dplyr)    
inner_join(df, df, by="group") %>% 
  filter(name.x != name.y) %>%
  select(V1 = name.x, V2 = name.y)

#    V1 V2
# 1   A  B
# 2   A  C
# 3   B  A
# 4   B  C
# 5   C  A
# 6   C  B
# 7   D  E
# 8   D  F
# 9   E  D
# 10  E  F
# 11  F  D
# 12  F  E
```